# How to use CookieAuthentication in dotnet core mvc properly?

Tags: c#, cookies, asp.net-core, middleware

My Configure:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {          
        app.UseCookieAuthentication( new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = "MyScheme",
            LoginPath = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString( "/Account/Login" ),
            AccessDeniedPath = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString( "/Account/Forbidden" ),
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge = true,
        } );

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

My ConfigureServices:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);

        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddAuthentication();
        services.AddAuthorization();
    }
```

the problem is that when i try to get any action with Authorize attribute,the server just reply with httpcode 401,however what i want is a httpcode 302.

Comment: How do you send request? Is it an ajax request? If so 401 status code is expected response.

Comment: @ademcaglin I send the request by a link. I just added **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies** to the project.json, then configured the service and used the middleware,finally added **Authorize** atrribute to my action.did i lose any thing?

Comment: If request is not an ajax request(doesn't contain `X-Requested-With`), normally you should get 302 response. I couldn't find any problem with your code.

Comment: @ademcaglin I changed the version of **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies** from **1.2.0-preview1-22851** to **1.0.0** then the problem was solved.now i am trying to find the release note of **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies**