# How to use CookieAuthentication in ASP.net core 1.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, cookies, asp.net-core

I'm new in ASP.net core and I managed to use [Cookie Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie) instead of my old Session Authentication way.I already followed steps in tutorial above and read [How to use CookieAuthentication in dotnet core mvc properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40927225/how-to-use-cookieauthentication-in-dotnet-core-mvc-properly)
 but I couldun't find way to use this authentication in my app.any simple example will help me.
**Startup.cs**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseBrowserLink();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    }
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationScheme = "MyScheme",
        LoginPath = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString("/Account/Login"),
        AccessDeniedPath = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString("/Account/Forbidden"),
        AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
        AutomaticChallenge = true,
    });
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
...
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);

    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddAuthentication();
    services.AddAuthorization();
}
```

**AccountController**

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public String Login()
    {
        return "Please login";
    }

    public String Forbidden()
    {
        return "Forbidden";
    }

}
```

Comment: What's the issue exactly, no login screen? You need to use the Authorize attribute on your controller or actions.

Comment: Check this [tutorials](http://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/05/13/cookie-authentication-asp-net-core/)

Comment: @Matt please give complete example.

Comment: You can look at msd's tutorial above plus [the Microsoft docs on identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity).